# ORACLE sql use variables for query

Tags: oracle, declare

i need to create variables for my query

i have a inner join query
Es

```
select * from ...
inner join
 etc ..
where username = 'jack'
and value 1 = 'work'
```

i'd like to create on top variables for easy change value in where condition.

I have used Declare and set but show me the error PLS-00103 for group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect

how can i do for create variables ?
thanks a lot for help, sorry for my English is not my first languages.

Comment: Are you working using Stored procedure to call this select?

Comment: no a simple select with inner join

Answer (score 1):

You can use Anonymus PL/SQL block for your above question. But if you are using select inside block, you should use `INTO` clause along with it.

E.g.--

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (AA VARCHAR2(20));

insert into t1 values('YYY');
commit;  -- table created with sample value.
```

Now, use Anonymus pl-sql block to call select -

```
DECLARE
USERNAME VARCHAR2(20);
VALUE1 VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
USERNAME:='YYY';

SELECT aa into  VALUE1 FROM T1 WHERE AA=USERNAME;

dbms_output.put_line(VALUE1);

end;
```

Now, in your case since you are using `select *` you can use `ROWTYPE` attribute to select the row from your table.
Check `ROWTYPE` example here. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#BEIBGEFH

Answer (score 0):

You have to embeded statements between begin and end.

```
Declare varchar2(30) vUserName := 'jack';
Declare ...
Begin
    select * from ...
    inner join
    etc ..
    where username = vUserName
          and value 1 = vValue1
End
```

Comment: You've got an extra Declare there; remove that as it's not necessary.

Comment: Report error -ORA-06550: Encountered the symbol "(" ....  is on the end of varchar2

Comment: ah, the variable name needs to go before the datatype. so: `vusername varchar2(30) := 'jack';`